# Wordpress can't detect any thumbnails size?

Tags: images, thumbnails

Wordpress can't detect any thumbnails size, I re-generated all image but not work.

The plugin (Simple Image Sizes) can detected all thumbnails size settings.
[image]

But when I want to use, it can't detect any size.
[image]

What should i do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a plugin is interfering with the WordPress media features. If possible, try deactivating the media/image plugins and see if anything changes.

You can also consider reinstalling the WordPress (wp-admin/update-core.php) It is recommended to back up your site before doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, my aws server doesn't have php-gd, just install it.

But, the second problem is wordpress doesn't upload files to correct path (current month is 2017/12), it always upload files to folder "01".